# Facebook login (connect) button rendering in chrome fails

Tags: html, css, facebook

Today I realized that FB login button no longer renders correctly in chrome (maybe because of browser update - who knows).
Take a look at this http://goo.gl/mK6sf website in both IE and Chrome. Each button has some extra 'padding-top' in chrome and the iframe is not hidden correctly.
Here is png preview http://goo.gl/sfUl5

**EDIT**
How to make FB login button to render correctly like in IE? Do you see similar issue on other websites? Has facebook changed something or it's Chrome to blame?

**EDIT2 2013-01-16**
Take a look at this thread: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/592452207446912 This is probably Facebook API error. I will post a response when they fix it.

Comment: After 45 second this error appears: `fb:login_button failed to resize in 45s`

Comment: I had the same problem. I answered the related problem
[here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20870280/2416112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Matt Bower from Facebook developer's forum the temporary solution is:

```
#fb_login_button { 
    width: 80px; 
}
#fb_login_button span, 
#fb_login_button iframe {.
    width: 80px! important;
    height: 25px! important;
}
```

I still wait for Facebook developers to fix this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use login plugin in iframe. Please use the JavaScript SDK and the XFBML or HTML5 implementations.
Try this code:

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: The code that I use is: `<fb:login-button class="fb-login-button" size="small" show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1" scope="{{ scope }}" autologoutlink="{{ autologoutlink }}">{{ label }}</fb:login-button>
` view webpage source and you will see that when you expand fb:login node there is iframe inside.