# fb:login_button failed to resize in 45s

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-login

I attempted to implement an asynchronous loading Facebook log in button, but the button disappeared after **45 seconds**.

This is the message I got in the error console:

> FB:login_button failed to re-size in 45s

Can someone show me a way to solve this bug?

Answer (score 6):

Matt Bower from Facebook developer's forum gave this temporary solution:

```
#fb_login_button { 
    width: 80px; 
}
#fb_login_button span, 
#fb_login_button iframe {.
    width: 80px !important;
    height: 25px !important;
}
```

Facebook Dev's are working to fix this error.

just so I'm not taking credit for someone else's answer the original answer can be found here:
[Facebook login (connect) button rendering in chrome fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358165/facebook-login-connect-button-rendering-in-chrome-fails)

Comment: This is an answer given to another person having this problem a little while back, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the CSS styles. I have added the CSS, but still I am getting this issue in Chrome and Firefox browser. Even though the Facebook login process is working perfectly the login/logout button will go hidden after 45sec.

Comment: I found it necessary to use `vertical-align:top` on the containing div element, but that is likely due to it also being `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this warning appear in my console:

> fb:post failed to resize in 45s

And I was able to fix it by renaming a div class from "fb-post" to "fbPost".  Try looking for an HTML element with an ID or class name of "fb-login" in your source.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same issue with a class named fb-like. Would have never thought to try this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also, watch out for the avast or other anti-tracking add in blocking access to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I was getting `fb:post failed to resize in 45s`.

Because I did not provide my Facebook app website URL. So go to your Facebook app settings and type your URL like this:

[image]

I used wampserver for hosting. You can put your own website URL.

Answer (score 0):

Also double check permissions that you are requesting with approved permissions. The example below **doesn't work** and generate the `fb:loginbutton not showing` error.

[image: Facebook approved items]

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,location" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Removing the `location` requirement will fix this example.